# Proving the set of quadratic numbers is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I don't really know where to start with this, thought I'd ask for some input. Here's the question:

*Prove that the set of quadratic numbers is countable.*

**EDIT**
The question says that a number is quadratic if it is a root of a degree two polynomial.

Comment: What is your definition of a "quadratic number?" I can think of a few...

Comment: Are you asking about square numbers like $1,4,9,16,25...$?

Comment: The question says that a number is quadratic if it is a root of a degree two polynomial.

Comment: The coefficients of the quadratic polynomial determine the nature of its roots.  If the coefficients are rational, then the quadratic numbers are countable.  If the coefficients are complex, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, i reworded your question as "is the number of quadratic (degree 2) extensions of Q countable ?"
This nicely restricts us to just (degree two) polynomials with rational coefficients, as clearly the complex or real case is uncountable. This is then a subset of all polynomials with rational coefficients, which is countable (algebraic integers are countable).